# Unexpected termination of pods

Tags: kubernetes, rpc

I have created a fresh charmed cluster using Juju bundle: [Kubernetes Calico #884](https://jaas.ai/u/containers/kubernetes-calico/bundle/884)

Running kubectl commands like `kubectl logs <podname> -f`, the terminal connection disconnects with error:

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
```

Note: I've encountered this frequently when interacting on the charmed Kubernetes instance. I never saw the error on the microk8s instance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug reported - https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-containerd/+bug/1883663

The fix is released in Rev88 of Containerd Charm.

command `juju upgrade-charm containerd` upgraded the containerd app on all the nodes in the mode, which fixed the issue.

Comment: this is already up to date for me